# Passing credentials or token from JS to PHP in google calendar API

Tags: javascript, php, google-calendar-api

I am not sure if this is even possible. I am trying to add events to a google calendar. Authorization via Javascript is working. I am able to get authorization from user. The user will sign in when they are filling out the form then submit the form for processing in the server. I need to insert the event after the form is submitting. This is because there are many validations before the form is processed. I would like to know if it is possible to pass access token or some validation so that the event can be added on server side with google api. So user logs in with JS but event is inserted with PHP. This is what I have so far.

```
token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
///user is logged in and I can get access token
$.ajax({

    url : 'aa_calendar.php',
    type : 'post',
    data : 'token='+token,
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(result) {              
        console.log(result);
        $("#content").html(result.msg);
    }
});
```

Now in aa_calendar.php

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Remote Sessions');


$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'));
$client->setAccessToken($_POST['token']);
```

this is the error I am getting
Uncaught Google_Auth_Exception: Could not json decode the token
I assume is not as easy as just passing a token :/

Thank you all for the help

Comment: Would it be an option for you to create the event in PHP with a service account?

Comment: that's the way I had to do it.